# How to find a specific variable from text and show it on qlineedit in qt?

Tags: qt, split, qlineedit

I am new with qt and trying to get some information from a text. like with the c++. I need to find some variable in the text and show them in the Qline edit. My file looks like this;
Prm1 536
 Prm2 200
 Prm3 456 
and it will go on. I will show every value in a different q line edit field.
I can find a specific line and show it on the qline edit with this code.
But this is not exactly I need.

```
 ifstream input;
    size_t pos;
    string line;

    input.open("D:/qt/project/QFileDemo/myfile.txt");
    if(input.is_open())
    {
   while(getline(input,line))
   {
    pos = line.find("<100>");
     if(pos!=string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
    {

         QFile file("D:/qt/project/QFileDemo/myfile.txt");
         if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
         {
             QMessageBox::warning(this,"title","file not open");

         }

         QTextStream in(&file);
         //QString text=in.readAll();
         QString text=in.readLine();

         ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);

         file.close();
```

so I tried splitting them. and showing on the qline field but no success.

```
QTextStream stream(stdin);
QString line;
do {
    line = stream.readLine();
    QStringList parts = line.split(";", QString::KeepEmptyParts);
    if (parts.length() == 2) {
        QString prm        = parts[0];
        QString firstName = parts[1];
```

When I do it, it doesn not readany thing. I have already read split function, QRegExp documentation on qt website but not so helpfull. Waiting for your help.

Comment: 1. Reading from STDIN in a GUI program is likely to cause trouble. Don't do that unless you understand the implications (blocking the event loop).  2. Try creating [mcve] which just reads the file and prints the strings, no GUI. Ask about that if you can't get it working yourself. Once it works, compare to the code you have in your GUI program.

Comment: Wellll, reading with gui is not easy, that's why I am asking here. With c++ I can do that. But I need to do it with gui. I need to do similar things with this video but with qt. It should split the line and show only one variable. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjJY7yA5SWw&list=LLqFbaYx1Aj9aria1mqE3D7A

Comment: If you need to read from stdin in Qt, and are on Unix, you can use QSocketNotifier. If you are on Windows, you basically have to use a separate thread, or Windows specific APIs. There is no standard C++, nor platform-independent Qt way to read stdin without blocking. Try creating that [mcve], if you want concrete help.

Comment: If you can avoid reading from stdin somehow (read from a regular file, or add GUI element to accept keyboard input), then do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that. There may be easier or shorter ways but this is what I did.

```
QFile file("D:/qt/project/Mparameters_ornek/mpfile.txt");
QTextStream in(&file);
QString text;
while (!in.atEnd()) {
text = in.readLine();
if (text.contains("Prm1"))

        break;
}
QString str = text;
QStringList list_str = str.split(";");
QString first = list_str.first();
QString last = list_str.back();
QTextEdit *txt = new QTextEdit();
 txt->setText(last);
ui->plainTextEdit_prm1->setPlainText(last);

     file.close();

 QTextStream in2(&file);
 QString text2;
 while (!in.atEnd()) {
     text2 = in2.readLine();
     if (text2.contains("Prm2"))
      break;
 }
 QString str2 = text2;
 QStringList list_str2 = str2.split(";");
 QString first2 = list_str2.first();
 QString last2 = list_str2.back();
 QTextEdit *txt2 = new QTextEdit();
  txt2->setText(last2);
 ui->plainTextEdit_prm2->setPlainText(last2);

 file.close();
```